# What's the difference between using / and # in a URL? Does it influence the analytics?

Tags: url

I'm creating a few new pages on my website and I'm wondering what is the best approach for the pages that are somehow related,either by topic, or the same category.

So, for example, Asana has one main page - `https://asana.com/terms`
and a few subpages, for Terms of Service, Privacy Policy, etc.

They have them like this:

```
https://asana.com/terms#terms-of-service  
https://asana.com/terms#privacy-policy
```

Can you explain why not like this?

```
https://asana.com/terms/terms-of-service  
https://asana.com/terms/privacy-policy
```

Or should it be the following?

```
https://asana.com/terms-of-service  
https://asana.com/privacy-policy
```

(GitLab has it this way: `https://about.gitlab.com/terms/`)

How would it influence my Google Analytics and what other influence might it have?

Answer (score 2):

`#` indicates a specific point in the page, an anchor point as they say. Meaning that when you visit the page with the `#` prefix your screen will automatically scroll to that portion of the page.

`/` indicates a subcategory or page under a category and when you visit it you will start from the top.

`#` Is used only for URL sharing or page formatting when you want the recipient to be immediately scrolled to a point of interest within the page upon clicking the link.

`/` is what you use to indicate hierarchy.

So `www.example.com/something/other` means that the *other* is a **page** under something.
On the other hand `www.example.com/something#other` means that the something is a page and that the *other* is a section of that page.

If you create new pages, use `/`.

Comment: What about the cases where `#` URLs are used to load content via AJAX?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Although in the OPs example, `#` is simply used to anchor a point on a single (massive) page - so that would seem to be why _they_ have used that particular URL structure.

Answer (score 1):

The `#` tag point out the location of the same page. Suppose if user is on this URL: `https://asana.com/terms` and then there is a button which called "terms of service" when user clicks on it the URL will be changed to `https://asana.com/terms#terms-of-service` but the page will not get changed instead of that, it will scroll the page to that fold where terms of services will be mentioned, as that folds CSS ID contains that name "terms-of-service" you can check it with inspect element or by going into the code.

[image]

Now this is a completely new page URL `https://asana.com/terms/terms-of-service` which will redirect you to the new page.